# Solving for $f$ when $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y) + axy$ where $a$ is a real number

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f$ be a real valued continuous function such that $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y) + axy$ where $a$ is a real number.
We have to show that $f(x) = \frac{a}{2}x^2 + bx$ where $b = f(1) - \frac{a}{2}$

Here is my solution so far:
Let $x = y = 0$ . This gives $f(0) = 0$
Now putting $y = -x$ gives $ax^2 = f(x) + f(-x)$. This gives $a = f(1) + f(-1)$

Also by letting $x = y$ we obtain $f(2x) = 2f(x) + ax^2$

After juggling with these equations I am not able to show that $f(x)$ is a quadratic equation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If $f$ is assumed differentiable at $x=0$ then there exist a very simple proof. Write the equation as: $\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} + ax$ and take $h\to 0$ to get $f'(x) = f'(0) + ax$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x) = f(x) - \frac{a}{2}x^2$.

Then, subtracting $\frac{a}{2}x^2 + \frac{a}{2}y^2$ from both sides of the given expression, we get :

$f(x+y) - \frac{a}{2}x^2 - \frac{a}{2}y^2 -axy = f(x) - \frac{a}{2}x^2 +f(y) - \frac{a}{2}y^2 $

$f(x+y) - (\frac{a}{2}(x+y))^2 = f(x) - \frac{a}{2}x^2 + f(y) - \frac{a}{2}y^2$

$g(x+y) = g(x) + g(y)$

This equation is known to have the solution $g(x) = bx$. ([Cauchy's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation))

Thus, $f(x)$ has the solution of the form $\frac{a}{2}x^2 + bx$.